# Dodging the Computer Virus's attacks

Tags: kirby-super-star

For those unfamiliar with the game, in Kirby Super Star, one of the bosses is called the Computer Virus, which is more or less an RPG style thing where you take turns attacking each other (while the boss is attacking you it's invulnerable, and it won't attack when it is vulnerable). Anyway, watching a youtuber do a no guard (and no ability) run of the arena, he claimed that the boss's star attack is undodgeable in the boss's first and third forms (the magician and dragon). If possible I'd like some verification.

Is it possible to dodge the stars attack in the first and third forms of the Computer Virus without an ability or guarding?

Here's the video of the fight requested.

(The video description contains a thorough description of the difficulties of the computer virus fight without abilities/guarding, as well as lots of cursing, you have been warned.)

Comment: Could you link to the youTube video in question?

Comment: Alright, link added, the boss in question starts at about the 1 minute mark.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not 100% on it, I can't think of a good way you can avoid the attack without either abilities or guarding. I'm speaking from my own attempts as well as never having seen it done elsewhere.

This *especially* goes for the first fight against the Witch, as she doesn't do any other attacks that can be used for 'countering'. In other words, in a no-ability run, you have to put yourself in a position to suck in at least one of the stars to do any damage, and given their speed you're probably not going to be able to jump/float/slide away and still have the reaction time necessary to get a star to shoot back.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the attack with a bunch of stars flying from the right side of the screen to the left? If so, I think you can get lucky and manually dodge all of the stars by flying, but besides that, there isn't much you can do. You can guard, however, and reduce the damage from the stars to almost nothing.